# How do I create synchronization mechanisms in managed shared memory segments?

Tags: c++, boost, interprocess

I'm trying to have 2 processes communicate via an stl container - so I've decided to use the managed shared memory. I'm trying to implement some synchronisation between them - an interprocess_mutex for a start with a scoped_lock - but I'm not having much luck. How is it supposed to be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best solution is a container handler, and all access (getter/setter) to the container through the handler. So in this handler you could implement the synchronisation easily.

Salu2.